# Console Application passing in inputs via form application

Tags: c#, parameters, console-application

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing arguments to a console application from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985088/passing-arguments-to-a-console-application-from-c-sharp)

I have a console application that I am running from a windows form application.  Currently it runs a process called dnaml.exe  The executable I need to hit y and  then , is there a way to have my windows form pass this info in?  I was able to start it from the form using a Process object.  Thanks!

Comment: duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354029/passing-arguments-to-a-console-application, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985088/passing-arguments-to-a-console-application-from-c-sharp

Comment: @nawfal, even tho the title is misleading, the question seems to be not so much arguments, but about writing to a Process's StandardInput stream.

Comment: please read those questions, these aren't parameters that are passed into an executable such as an installer or 7zip, these are inputs that have to be put in

Comment: @Badmiral in that case pls update ur title. Furthermore show us some relevant code you have used

Comment: @Badmiral, it might help to reword the question. But DoomMuffins answer is what you're looking for

Comment: done, hopefully that is a more accurate version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write it to the `StandardInput` of the `Process` object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx

Answer (score -3):

Use this overload of [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx).

Comment: If you read the question straight though, you'd realize it wasn't about arguments, as it was "simulating key presses".

Comment: Even reading the question it wasn't clear that this was about stdin IMO.

Comment: @hometoast - The question is really vague.  While I agree this answer itself is vague itself, the author did his best, but its still a bad answer.